# Using powershell how to add content with one header column

Tags: powershell

Code:

```
$path = 'C:\Users\Desktop\Test.csv' 
If (Test-Path $path) 
{
Remove-Item $path -verbose 
}
else { Write-Host "$path not found" }

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Storage.Vds") | Out-Null
$oVdsServiceLoader = New-Object Microsoft.Storage.Vds.ServiceLoader
$oVdsService = $oVdsServiceLoader.LoadService($null) 
$oVdsService.WaitForServiceReady() 
$oVdsService.Reenumerate() 
$cDisks = ($oVdsService.Providers |% {$_.Packs}) |% {$_.Disks}
$cPacks = $oVdsService.Providers |% {$_.Packs} 

foreach($oPack in $cPacks)
{
    If($oPack.Status -eq "Online" -and $oPack.Volumes -ne $null)
    {
         foreach($oDisk in $oPack.Disks)
        {
             foreach($oVolume in $oPack.Volumes)
            {

            $data= new-object psobject -Property @{
                'DiskGuid' = $oDisk.DiskGuid
                'Name' = $oDisk.FriendlyName
            }
            

            
            }
            
            }
            $final = $data | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "|" -NoTypeInformation 
            $final | Add-Content $path 

            
        }
    }
}
```

Output in CSV file

| "Name" | "DiskGuid" |
| --- | --- |
| "DELL PERC H740P Mini SCSI Disk Device" | "5b932319-8cb4-4909-96c0-f85db3671c91" |
| "Name" | "DiskGuid" |
| "DELL PERC H740P Mini SCSI Disk Device" | "5b932319-8cb4-4909-96c0-f85db3671c91" |
| "Name" | "DiskGuid" |
| "HITACHI OPEN-V Multi-Path Disk Device" | "2f3563e7-66c9-4a8a-9bea-d3e856b839eb" |
| "Name" | "DiskGuid" |
| "HITACHI OPEN-V Multi-Path Disk Device" | "2f3563e7-66c9-4a8a-9bea-d3e856b839eb" |

Expected output in CSV:

| "Name" | "DiskGuid" |
| --- | --- |
| "DELL PERC H740P Mini SCSI Disk Device" | "5b932319-8cb4-4909-96c0-f85db3671c91" |
| "DELL PERC H740P Mini SCSI Disk Device" | "5b932319-8cb4-4909-96c0-f85db3671c91" |
| "HITACHI OPEN-V Multi-Path Disk Device" | "2f3563e7-66c9-4a8a-9bea-d3e856b839eb" |
| "HITACHI OPEN-V Multi-Path Disk Device" | "2f3563e7-66c9-4a8a-9bea-d3e856b839eb" |

Anyone could help how to get the values as displayed in expected output?

Comment: i have updated code. That line of code i have removed not required.

Comment: are you looking for the `FriendlyName` of the Disk or for the Volume? because I see with your current code that you're creating duplicated objects. Maybe you're looking to combine the GUID of the Disk with the FriendlyName of each volume of that Disk?

Comment: i need both  information. i will combine  the GUID of the Disk with the FriendlyName of each volume of that Disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is invoking `ConvertTo-Csv` per each object in your loop and appending it to a file. This is causing each appended object to have a header and single row. What you should do instead is pipe the output from your expression directly to `Export-Csv`.

It is also recommended, for simplicity, readability and performance to use the newer syntax with [`pscustomobject` type accelerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.4) instead of the old syntax with `New-Object PSObject`.

```
$oVdsService.Providers.Packs | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Status -ne 'Online') {
        return
    }

    foreach ($disk in $_.Disks) {
        if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($disk.DriveLetter)) {
            continue
        }

        [pscustomobject]@{
            DiskGuid = $disk.DiskGuid
            Name     = $disk.FriendlyName
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv $path -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: csv file empty using this method.

Comment: @Shan missed `.Packs` my bad. try with the updated code

Comment: i have tried it load data but looping without stopped and only having DiskGuid  values.

Comment: @Shan seems like the loop for volumes is not needed at all. see if that update works